# Linux Mint brightness has too few settings

Tags: linux-mint, display-settings, brightness

There are many questions to do with screen brightness on Linux Mint ([this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103023/ubuntu-mint-brightness-0-by-default-on-login) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30924/how-do-i-set-default-brightness-after-boot) refer to default brightness being zero, and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66365/the-brightness-on-my-lenovo-sl510-only-moves-between-100-and-0) to there being only two brightness levels.)

My problem is a bit different: I have *too few* brightness levels to choose from when using the function keys.

There are only three settings between full and completely off! If I'm working in a dark room, I need a very low brightness, but it still needs to be more than off!

I have Linux Mint 17 running on an HP Envy 14. The brightness settings in `Screensaver and Lock Settings` works better than the function keys do (I can get a dimmer level there) but it's still not brilliant.

Comment: Do you have files in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` or `/sys/class/backlight` ? A file called `brightness` would be a great place to start.

Comment: Yes! In `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` the file `brightness` contains `1 6`. In `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1` the same file contains `1 6`. In `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` it contains `1 2907`.

Comment: Files in `/sys/class/backlight` will allow you to control your brightness at a file level. For instance, `max_brightness` files set your maximum brightness level. `brightness` and `actual_brightness` control your current brightness level. Write to these files and see how things change ;)

Comment: Wow. How interesting! Isn't Linux endlessly fascinating! Any idea how I can write to `max_brightness`?

Comment: Just like you write to any other file. Use an [editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor), or a [shell redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

Comment: @JohnWHSmith but what if the permitted values are only 1 to 12?